# C++ function call segfault on static function

Tags: c++, function, static, header, segmentation-fault

I have a header like this in a class and I want to use the function in the constructor of the same class as a static function call:

```
class JsonReader {
   public:

   /// functions implementation including constructor and what not

   static string encrypt(const string& str_in, const string& key, const string& iv) {
       string str_out;
       // implementation of the function
       return str_out;
   }

}
```

Now at the constructor it fails on this line of code:

```
string tmp = encrypt(text, key, NULL);
```

text & key are valid strings.  I also verified that the implementation of the function is correct if I directly copy the code from the function body to the constructor.  So the only issue should be somewhere at the interface with the header or function call at the constructor.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can `iv` which is a reference be NULL?

Comment: oops... that's right... thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're passing `NULL` to a parameter which takes `const std::string &`. Passing `NULL` will cause a construction of a temporary `std::string` off of `NULL`, which means you end up calling the constructor that expects a **non-null** `const char *`. I'm guessing you don't actually use `iv` in your implementation, which is why when you manually inlined the implementation, the problem went away.